# Shortest path with odd length (linear time)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Question:

Given a graph $G$, How can we find the shortest path from vertex $x$ to $y$ with odd length?

Note: The time complexity is important to me.  Can we somehow modify Breadth-first Search to do the trick?

Comment: Do you need to use each edges at most once?

Comment: @Smylic yes! its like the shortest path problem... but the length should be odd!

Comment: That makes the problem harder. I can only tell you solution when double pass through an edge is allowed.

Comment: @Smylic what do you mean by double pass? u cound every 2 edges 1?

Comment: Let look at this graph: $G = (\{\,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\,\}, \{\,\{\,1, 2\,\}, \{\,2, 3\,\}, \{\,3, 4\,\}, \{\,4, 5\,\}, \{\,5, 6\,\}, \{\,4, 6\,\}\,\})$. There is a [walk](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Walk.html) of odd length from vertex 3 to vertex 1. But there is no [trail](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trail.html) of an odd length between these vertices. In greater graphs it is possible when there is a trail of an odd length, but traversing an edge twice allows you to get a shorter walk of an odd length.

Comment: @Smylic well, i'm sorry but that's not what i want

Answer (score 1):

A very elegant answer to the question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187555/shortest-paths-from-s-by-weight-which-contain-even-number-of-edges).

---

Alternatively, you could always do it with a MIP: use binary variables $x_{ij}$ that take value $1$ if and only if edge $(i,j)$ is used, and minimize
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_{ij}
$$
subject to 
$$
\begin{cases}
\mbox{usual flow constraints} \\
\sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_{ij}=2k+1\\
k \in \mathbb{N}\\
x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}
\end{cases}
$$

Of course, the complexity is exponential so that is a major flaw to this method if theoretic time complexity is important. But it would be interesting to see how computation times evolve in practice, as the implementation is straightforward.

Comment: Solution you post link to gives a shortest even walk, not a shortest even trail (see comments to this question).

Comment: I wrote that time complexity is important to me. I mentioned that the solution should be in linear time. I said "odd". With all of these, what is this answer??!!

Comment: Just sharing ideas, don't be so harsh..The link I posted gives a method for "even" paths, but if you read carefully it gives you "odd" paths at the same time (by considering vertices $(i',j')$). And yes, I agree the second method is off subject if you want linear time, but I put it there as an alternative, it is not my main answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is directed, the problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard.
If the graph is undirected, the problem is polynomial.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40433693/18691245) and this paper:
*LaPaugh, Andrea S.; Papadimitriou, Christos H.*, [**The even-path problem for graphs and digraphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/net.3230140403), Networks 14, 507-513 (1984). [ZBL0552.68059](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0552.68059).